# snowflake COPY INTO file - how to generate multiple files with a fixed size

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I'm using below COPY INTO to generate file from table to s3

```
COPY INTO @s3_stage FROM my_sf_table
FILE_FORMAT = (
TYPE=CSV
compression=GZIP
EMPTY_FIELD_AS_NULL = false
NULL_IF = ('')
FIELD_DELIMITER=',')
single = false
max_file_size=4900000000;
```

I was able to get a 300MB file and uploaded to s3. However the maximum file size I can upload is 100 MB - I then changed max_file_size to 104857600(100MB)

```
COPY INTO @s3_stage FROM my_sf_table
FILE_FORMAT = (
TYPE=CSV
compression=GZIP
EMPTY_FIELD_AS_NULL = false
NULL_IF = ('')
FIELD_DELIMITER=',')
single = false
max_file_size=104857600;
```

My expectation: get three files, each file is 100MB, and upload to s3. But it's not working, I've still got one 300 MB file. Anyone knows why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your expectation isn't correct here, as you will not get 3 files of 100MB.  You will get a number of files determined by the size of the warehouse you are using to run the statement.  However, that does not explain why you are still getting just 1 file.  I believe this line in the documentation might be the issue, but not sure.  Please take a look and let me know.  I can modify the answer, if needed.

> Boolean that specifies whether to generate a single file or multiple files. If FALSE, a filename prefix must be included in path.

This would indicate that you need a filename as part of your path.  You don't have one, so perhaps it defaults to TRUE and only creates a single file.